# How to pass string user input (RGB) to VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a userform with RGB values to be assigned to shapes that will be later created by the macro:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With lstChosenColor
        lstChosenColor.AddItem "RGB(0, 0, 0)"
        lstChosenColor.AddItem "100, 100, 100" 'different from the above to show one alternative of my trials
    End With

End Sub
```

However I do not know how to insert the selected value into the macro itself. I tried in many ways:

```
    Dim lstChosenColor As String 'somewhere else i saw it as Long, tried but without success
'   Dim ChosenColor As String
'   ChosenColor = lstChosenColor 'I tried this one, too



        If lstChosenColor = False Then
            MsgBox "No Color Selected"
        Else: New_Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lstChosenColor.Selected 'I tried also 'New_Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lstChosenColor and 'New_Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(lstChosenColor)
        End If



            Set New_Shape = myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeOval, Left:=Shp_Cntr - ((Shp.Width + 2) / 2), Top:=Shp_Mid - ((Shp.Width + 2) / 2), Width:=Shp.Width, Height:=Shp.Width)
'            New_Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(lstChosenColor) 'I commented this as it is part of a repeating block for a various number of shapes and I thought I could assign the RGB value above
```

Could anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use (eg) "100, 100, 100" as the value you can do something like:

```vb
Dim v, arr

v = lstChosenColor.Value              'get selected value

arr = Split(Replace(v, " ", ""), ",") 'remove any spaces and split to array 

'assign each array element as an argument to RGB()
New_Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(CLng(arr(0)), CLng(arr(1)), CLng(arr(2)))
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, just to understand the syntax, "Dim v, arr" does not say what kind of variables they are, or does it? I mean, as there is no "As something", what would they be?

Comment: @Bradipo If you Dim a variable w/o specifying "as {sometype}" the variable is DIMmed as a variant. Convenient in this case because a variant can contain pretty much anything, including arrays. You could as well Dim v as a string in this case.

Comment: @TimWilliams
Thank you, it works.
For possible future readers, "lstChosenColor.AddItem "(0, 0, 0)" would be the way to set the items so this solution works

Comment: "(0, 0, 0)" would give a Type Mismatch error on `CLng(arr(0))` since you'd be trying to cast `(100` to a Long...    Ditto  `CLng(arr(2))`

Comment: @TimWilliams
Yes, my bad, I should have removed the parenthesis, now I cannot edit the comment anymore
Correct is
"lstChosenColor.AddItem "0, 0, 0"

Comment: Older comments can't be edited but can be deleted - will delete mine above shortly if you'd like to do the same for yours ;-)

Comment: I think it can stay, after all you gave one more explanation that can be useful in the future for people like me who are learning. I am jumping from code to SO for almost every line of code and sometimes I find the answer in comments that an expert would regard as useless, but for a learner they are treasure. Also I would like  the upvote I gave you  to stay :)

Comment: Ok that's good point.